# Resize images in GridView on Android

Tags: android, image, gridview, image-size

I follow this tutorial to create a **[GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)**:

This line:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

Size 85x85 is great for my Wildfire, but on HTC Desire it looks very small.
How can I change the image size according to the screen?

I have 2 different layouts, but `Gridview` hasn't any attribute in the XML files to change the image size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to make an adjustment based off the pixel density of the current device you are on.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(lowVal, lowVal));
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(medVal, medVal));
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(highVal, highVal));
                 break;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this answer is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindowManager()

Comment: Syed, If you are using fragments you'll have to get the Activity first:
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

Answer (score 6):

Similar to willytate's answer, but you're better off creating a [dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) value in an xml (for 85dp) and retrieving it like so:

```
  int size = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_dimension);
```

That way, the width/height will be sized consistently, without you having to worry about much.

Comment: This is a nicer way of doing it